# Angular2 - ng-class not applying css

Tags: angular, ng-class

I'm just trying to implement a condition row formatting in a table but it is not working.

The code is very simple:

## styles

```
<style type="text/css">
  .red {
    color: red;
  }

  .blue {
    color: blue;
  }
</style>
```

## html component

```
<tr *ngFor="let c of customers" [class.selected]="c === selectedItem" ng-class="{1==1 ? 'red': 'blue'}">
```

The condition `1==1` is always `true`, and should render the red class,  but it doesn't apply either red or blue class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I created this example.

```
<div>
  <h2 [ngClass]="1==1?'red':'blue'">Hello {{name}}</h2>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Edgar, this helped me a lot ! The problem was due to the { } bracket,,, Without them it works !

Comment: No problem. In my company we started angular 2 a few months ago. So I'm proficient at best. So you removed the curly brackets and it works with ng-class? but that directive is angular 1 not 2. I'm surprised it works.

Comment: Yes, I grant you that works... But now I'm a bit confused... May be I'm running a different version than expected ?

Comment: Please have a look, go to the template directives section
https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/ajs-quick-reference.html

I will also test it in a bit.

Comment: Please have a look and play around, this is a simple test in angular 2. 
https://plnkr.co/edit/SxwBLCCQQylsoUGgdvN5?p=preview

I've tried using ng-class instead of [ngClass] and it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

html component

```
<tr *ngFor="let c of customers" [class.selected]="c === selectedItem" [ngClass]="{1==1 ? 'red': 'blue'}">
```